# Array structures can contain strings, which can be different lengths (and thus different sizes in memory). How is this possible?

Tags: arrays, string, data-structures

I am learning data structure.I have learned about the array that all elements should be the same size. 
So for example if there is an array A of containing integers and integer takes 4 byte.If base address of array A is X then we can calculate the address of nth element by adding Base address +(n-1)*size of element.

For example address of 2nd element=X+b
address of 3rd element=X+2b

If we consider an Array of string then how the above formula works, because string size is not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern programming languages, String data types are implemented as objects, and an array of Strings is in reality an array of *references* (pointers if you wish) to String objects, and references have a fixed, known size.

In general - in arrays of basic data types, each position will store the actual data. In arrays of objects, each position will contain a reference to the object, which resides somewhere else in memory and can be of any size (memory permitting.)

Comment: Thanks  I understood the concept now.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure (e.g. Array) doesn't include the string at all: It contains some reference to the string (e.g. a pointer), that is of fixed size. So when adding a string to the structure, that string is created elsewhere in memory, then a reference to it is added to the array.